# gnu make target variable not expanded properly

Tags: gnu-make

I'm confused at why stack_name is not being populated.  I've defined the variables, and they are not passed to other make tasks; in this case `deploy`

```
deploy-blog: distribution_id = blah
deploy-blog: AWS_PROFILE = blog
deploy-blog: domain_name = blog.example.com
deploy-blog: stack_name = $(subst .,-,${domain_name})
deploy-blog: deploy
```

If I call make a second time, the same thing happens...

```
deploy-blog: distribution_id = blah
deploy-blog: AWS_PROFILE = blog
deploy-blog: domain_name = blog.example.com
deploy-blog: stack_name = $(subst .,-,${domain_name})
deploy-blog:
    $(MAKE) deploy
```

I must explicitly pass them to the `deploy` target...

```
deploy-blog: distribution_id = blah
deploy-blog: AWS_PROFILE = blog
deploy-blog: domain_name = blog.example.com
deploy-blog: stack_name = $(subst .,-,${domain_name})
deploy-blog:
    $(MAKE) deploy distribution_id=${distribution_id} AWS_PROFILE=${AWS_PROFILE} domain_name=${domain_name} stack_name=${stack_name}
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I make this work without calling make again?
3. How can I title this question to be more in line with what people might search for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to the way you use variables in your `deploy` target.

```
deploy-blog: distribution_id = blah
deploy-blog: AWS_PROFILE = blog
deploy-blog: domain_name = blog.example.com
deploy-blog: stack_name = $(subst .,-,${domain_name})
deploy-blog: deploy

deploy:
   @echo "distribution_id=$(distribution_id) AWS_PROFILE=$(AWS_PROFILE) domain_name=$(domain_name) stack_name=$(stack_name)"
```

This example produces the following result, with variables correctly expanded.

```sh
make deploy-blog

# distribution_id=blah AWS_PROFILE=blog domain_name=blog.example.com stack_name=blog-example-com
```

However, if `$(stack_name)` is expanded more than once, the command is executed each time. To avoid that you can use a **simple variable** with `:=` that will be expanded only once.

```
stack_name := $(subst .,-,${domain_name})
```